# How can I remove the blank line caused by an empty sub-report? (Digital Metaphors Report builder)

Tags: subreport, reportbuilder

I created a report with a sub-report but not every line in the main report has something in the sub-report. So when it prints the empty sub-report prints a blank line. How do I get rid of the blank lines?

Answer (score 0):

Set the detail band of the subreport to dynamic height. This will cause it to shrink to the amount of space needed. No data = 0 height.